# Get the index of certain value of JSON Objects

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I have json data that I am pushing to an array. I need to get the index value of a certain ID value. I have tried IndexOf but it doesnt seem to work.

I have attached a snippet of my code and array. Along with a link to the JSON file for you to use.

I have added a comment to highlight the problem area. I have also sent a screenshot of the array being console.logged and the value I need to get.

```js
var posts;
var imgTitle;
var imgLink;
var url = 'http://www.capetownetc.com/api/get_category_posts/?slug=';
var counter = 1;
var postID;
var callFunction = true;
var articleContent;
var titleMaxLength = 28;
var articleArray = [];
var topicName = 'news';
var pageNumber;
var linkID;

//POST CARDS

function postCards(pageNumber, cardLimit, container, topic) {

    topicName = topic || 'news';
    pageNumber = pageNumber || 1;
    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET'
        , url: url + topicName + '&count=10&page=' + pageNumber
        , data: {
            get_param: 'value'
        }
        , dataType: 'jsonp'
        , success: function postPop(data) {
            $('.main-content').append('<div class="card-container card-container' + container + '"></div>');
            $.each(data.posts, function(i){
            
                posts = data.posts[i];
                imgTitle = data.posts[i].title;
                imgLink = data.posts[i].thumbnail_images.medium.url;
                imgTitle = imgTitle.substr(0, titleMaxLength);
                postID =  data.posts[i].id;
                
                $('.card-container' + container).append('<a href="' + postID + '" class="article-link" onclick="postArticle(' + i + ',' + pageNumber +')"><div class="card card1"><img src="' + imgLink + '" class="card-img"><span><h2 class="card-heading">' + imgTitle + '</h2></span></div></a>');
                
                $('#loading').css('opacity' , '0');
                
                callFunction = true;
                
                //JSON CONTENT TO ARRAY
                articleArray.push(posts);
                //**PROBLEM AREA - I need to get the ID position of the posts in this array, see    screenshot -
                if(window.location.hash) {
                
                    mainView.router.load({
                        content: newPageContent,
                        animatePages: true
                    });

                    articleContent = articleArray[i].content;

                    $('.article-container').html(articleContent);
                    console.log('hash');
                } 
                else {
                    
                }

            });
            console.log(articleArray);
        }
        
        }).done(function(){
            myApp.hidePreloader();
        });
        myApp.showPreloader();
}

postCards(counter, 10, counter);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                            
                            <div class="main-content">

                            </div>
```

[JSON Data File](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=30599191172096356643)

[image: The value which position I need to get]

Comment: So you want the index of the item you just pushed into an array? Well then check the length property of that array ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to get the index of the particular item by ID then first of all you have to get the item object by ID as below and then you can use indexOf to get the index of that particular item.

```
var item = yourArray.find(function (e) {
                        if (e.id == "your Id") {
                            return e;
                        }
                    });

var index = yourArray.indexOf(item);
```